# R CMD build - possible from within R?

Tags: r

Is it possible to build packages from within R instead of from the command line calling R?  I looked at ?build help file and also goggled but no luck.  Maybe its not possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, using build, check, etc from the "devtools" package.

```
library("devtools")
help (package="devtools")
```

Answer (score 11):

It *has* to be possible (but not necessarily easy).  `R CMD build` used to be a Perl script, but it's been a pure R function for some time; I can't remember the exact version when the switch occurred.

I (again) urge you to search for answers via [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org) (not Google) before asking here.  The 6th hit for `"R CMD build"` is [build.R](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/tools/R/build.R) from the svn repository.  I bet you could take a look at that script and figure out how to build a package from R.

If that doesn't work, you can always issue a shell command from R: `system("R CMD build myPackage.tar.gz")`.

Comment: thanks! I did use rseek this time, but didn't think to look through build.R and thought that someone would have asked this before.  It seems that the safest thing to do is just use R CMD build or system(...)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually possible by calling `tools:::.build_packages('pkname')`. You can also add arguments, i.e.: `tools:::.build_packages(c('--md5', 'pkname'))`.
But be aware that this will quit your R session after completion so I don't know how useful it is.